# What are "functions" starting with $ called, and where can I get a complete list of them?

Tags: verilog

In Verilog, there seem to be a whole family of functions (?) that start with `$`, such as `$display`, `$write`, `$time`, etc.

What are those objects? What are they called, and where can I get a comprehensive list and documentation for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that start with a `$` are referred to as *system* tasks and functions.

The Verilog 2001 Spec (IEEE 1364-2001) lists these in Chapter 17, "System tasks and functions." This covers common ones such as `$display`, `$finish`, `$time`, etc.

You will also see user-defined system tasks and functions.  These are described in Chapter 20.2 of 1364-2001.  Simulator vendors and library developers often define additional system tasks/functions which they should provide documentation for.